# Apache Redirect of 2 folders to another folder or network share

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I need to redirect 2 folders under /var/www/web1/data and /var/www/web1/users to either /mnt/network1/data and /mnt/network1/users. These are 2 network shares I have made to put all the static content of the web folders on here.

I've tried to use RewriteRule and ProxyPass but with no success

Am I doing something wrong or is this the wrong approach?

My apache rule for RewriteRule was

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /var/www/web1/data/ /mnt/network1/data/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want isn't mod_rewrite, but [mod_alias (specifically the `Alias` directive)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias):

```
Alias /data /mnt/network1/data/
Alias /users /mnt/network1/users
```

The first parameter is the request URI, and the second is a physical directory on your system. Mod_rewrite won't match against physical directories. This will make it so requests for http://your.domain.com/data/something/blah will be served from the physical directory `/mnt/network1/data/something/blah`. This is assuming that /var/www/web1/ is your webroot and your /mnt/network1/ permissions are set to something appropriate for apache.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a symbolic link?

```
ln -s /mnt/network1/data /var/www/web1/data

ln -s /mnt/network1/users /var/www/web1/users
```